# show/ hide items in the listbox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I make a listbox and it works perfectly, I also made a search function, but I want to hide the items in the listbox and show them only when searched through index.
here is my code for adding items

```
private void Savebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    addTolist(gatherItem());
    refreshView();
}

private void addTolist(Person p)
{
    Person.listperson.Add(p);
}

private void refreshView()
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(getItem());
}

private String getItem()
{
    String result = null;
    foreach (Person p in Person.listperson)
    {
        result = p.lastname;
    }
    return result;
}
```

and this is my code for search

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = listBox1.FindString(textBox6.Text);
    if (0 <= index)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
    }
}
```

Is there a way for this? thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way to do this with winforms. It a lot easier with WPF. With winforms you will have to `remove` the items. You could technically use databinding, but its not recommended at all, because listbox is supposed to used directly from your code according the MSDN documentation.

On second thought, you could overdraw the listbox and set the item you want to hide to transparent or something, buts its not easy. You may want to consider storing all your values in an array and then loop through array and only adding the elements you want. Or switch to WPF.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm deciding to hide the listbox where they are inserted and then transfer the searched items in the visible listbox, it's possible but I think it will be hard coded :(

Comment: @AlfredSanz That would work, or you could use an array like I mentioned

Answer (score 0):

You can cover a dummy ListBox on your origin one, and set origin one invisible.
Then you can archive the same effect by writing codes like

```
class DummyItem {
        public string text;
        public int index;
        public override string ToString() {
        return text;
    }
}

public void build_dummy() {
    listbox_dummy.Items.Clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < listbox_origin.Items.Count; i++) {

        // replace with your own judgement
        if (! should_hide(listbox_origin.Items[i])) {
            DummyItem item = new DummyItem();
            item.text = listbox_origin.Items[i].ToString();
            item.index = i;
            listbox_dummy.Items.Add(item);
        }

    }
}

private void listbox_dummy_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var item = (DummyItem) listbox_dummy.SelectedItem;
    var index = item.index;
    listbox_origin.SelectedIndex = index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this, is to create a `List<string>` item that will store removed items (or items that do not match the search-phrase given in `textbox1`), an `int` variable that will store how many characters there were the last time the `TextChanged` event was triggered, and then create a function for your listbox element that activates when the phrase in a textbox is updated:

`private void textbox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {}`

in this function, there are two things that could happen:

- if a character was added to `textbox1`:

  - you iterate over the elements in your `listbox`.
  - remove the ones that do not contain the phrase in `textbox1`
- if a character was removed from `textbox1`:

  - look through the `List<string>` variable you made to store the values you removed from your `listbox`
  - add back each item that fits the text in `textbox1` (check for duplicates though)

Here's the code I wrote to use as reference:

```
private List<string> temporarilyRemovedSongs = new List<string>();
private int previousTextLength = 0;
private void filter_songs_textbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> toRemove = new List<string>();
    string text = Tools.Strip(this.filter_songs_textbox.Text.ToLower());

    if (text.Length > this.previousTextLength)
    {
        // a char was added, remove songs that do not start with the search-phrase
        foreach (string song in this.songs_list.Items)
        {
            if (!song.ToLower().Contains(text))
            {
                this.temporarilyRemovedSongs.Add(song);
                toRemove.Add(song);
            }
        }

        foreach (string song in toRemove)
        {
            this.songs_list.Items.Remove(song);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // a char was removed; look through removed songs to add back
        foreach (string song in this.temporarilyRemovedSongs)
        {
            if (song.Contains(text) && !this.songs_list.Items.Contains(song))
                this.songs_list.Items.Add(song);
        }
    }
    previousTextLength = text.Length;
}
```